# Cordova local landing page with remote App and relative Paths

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

In my cordova project i have a local landing page, but im loading a remote App into it.

Im trying to achieve that some of the remote App resources (3rd party libs), are loaded from www/assets and the rest is facing the server.

The Problem is the App needs to be runnable in the browser and in the app. Is there a Plugin or something to achieve this?